# IssuesFlashing AT Firmware to ESP8266 chip built onto Arduino Mega board

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am attempting to flash an ESP8266EX that is built into an Arduino Mega board. I have 2 boards, both from factory I connect with a serial terminal (at 74880 baud chip default rate) and get the error message:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 

tail 8

chksum 0x2d

csum 0x2d

v00000000

~ld
```

I understand the firmware on the chip from factory should allow me to connect at 115200 and communicate using AT commands.

I have successfully flashed the firmware onto one of the boards using the Arduino IDE and the code below to create a wifi network that I can connect to with my phone, so I know at least one of the boards works, (just not with factory firmware?)

```
//  Set the DIP switches on the actual board to 1=OFF 2=OFF 3=OFF 4=OFF 5=ON 6=ON 7=ON 8=OFF 
//(USBESP8266 (Update firmware or sketch))

//Under Tools select Board then select the Generic esp8266 Module

//Paste the following sketch into the IDE, save and upload

// Create a WiFi access point and provide a web server on it. 


#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

/* Set these to your desired credentials. */
const char *ssid = "Mega";
const char *password = "12345678";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

/* Just a little test message. Go to the IP address you setup below in a web browser
connected to this access point to see it.
*/
void handleRoot() {
server.send(200, "text/html", "Hey Dirtbug");
}
void setup() {
delay(1000);
Serial.begin(57600);
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Configuring access point…");
//--------------------------------------------

IPAddress local_IP(192,168,0,20);

IPAddress gateway(192,168,0,1);

IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

Serial.print("Setting soft-AP configuration … ");

Serial.println(WiFi.softAPConfig(local_IP, gateway, subnet) ? "Ready" : "Failed!");

Serial.print("Setting soft-AP … ");

Serial.println(WiFi.softAP("ESPsoftAP_01") ? "Ready" : "Failed!");

Serial.print("Soft-AP IP address = ");
Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());


//--------------------------------------------

/* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */

WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

// IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();

Serial.print("AP IP address: ");

//Serial.println(myIP);

server.on("/", handleRoot);

server.begin();

Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}

void loop() 
{

server.handleClient();

}
```

This code works fine. get data in the serial monitor and displays it no issues.

I have tried to flash it with "ESP_8266_NONOS_SDK"(v2.2.1 and v3.0.4) and "ESP8266-IDF-ATV2.2.1.0" using esptools in python, or  flashing programs "flash_download_tool_v3.8.8" and "nodemcu-flasher-master" I am always getting these errors or variations of. I am using the following settings as they work in the arduino code:

[image: flash settings in arduino IDE]

I have used these settings when configuring the flashing tools, and .bin addresses as shown in this table here from the manufacturer (4096 512+512 for the 32Mb flash):

[image: .bin addresses for flashing]

But I'm still getting very similar error codes to above through serial monitor.

Ideally I want to use AT commands through the inbuilt serial between the Mega and ESP8266 to send and receive small packets of information in an SQL database.

Where can I start to try get this thing to work? Is there any Arduino sketch that will give me AT commands? Is there any particular settings I can try tweak to get the firmware to flash properly?

Thanks for your time. I really appreciate any help that can be offered!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got AT commands to work using the following settings and addresses!
[image]

Havn't tested much functionality yet but so far so good!